# Flexbox - Section stepping over footer

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'm really new to CSS Layouts and the thing is that I don't understand why my section that is a flexBox containing 2 divs, one text, and one image is stepping over the footer, I thought that it should push the content down back getting over it. I left an image and the code.. btw I know the CSS is kinda messed up, my real doubt is why the image taking the footer space instead of pushing it down. Thanks a lot!

[image]

```css
.header{
  padding:50px;
  background-color: #0b090a;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  color: #fefae0;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #628395;
  height: 75vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items:inherit;
}

.nav{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #161a1d;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav div{
  color: #fefae0;
  padding:1rem;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.aside{
  background-color: #a4161a;
  flex:2 1 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  order: 1
}

.aside p{
  font-family: 'Luxurious Roman', cursive;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.section .content {
  background-color: #fefae0;
  flex: 75%;
  padding: 1rem;
  order:0;
}

.section .shelby{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex: 75%;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  height:450px;
  background-color: #776a19
}

.section p{
  font-family: 'Luxurious Roman', cursive;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.shelby img{
  height:350px;
  width:500px;
}

footer{
  background-color: #660708;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<header className="header">
  <h1>Layout Testing</h1>
</header>

<nav className="nav">
  <div>This is the Navbar tho</div>
  <div> Barra de navegacion</div>
  <div>Seccion de rutas </div>
</nav>

<div className="container">
  <aside className="aside">
    <h2>Aside</h2>
    <p>
      Overview Peaky Blinders is an epic centered on a gangster family of
      Irish-Romani origin set in Birmingham, England, starting in 1919,
      several months after the end of the First World War in November
      1918. The story centres on the Peaky Blinders gang and their
      ambitious and highly cunning boss Tommy Shelby (Cillian Murphy).
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section className="section">
    <div className="content">
    <h2>Section</h2>
    <p>
      Peaky Blinders is a British period crime drama television series
      created by Steven Knight. Set in Birmingham, England, the series
      follows the exploits of the Peaky Blinders crime gang in the direct
      aftermath of the First World War. The fictional gang is loosely
      based on a real urban youth gang of the same name, who were active
      in the city from the 1890s to the early 20th century. Peaky Blinders
      features an ensemble cast, led by Cillian Murphy, Helen McCrory, and
      Paul Anderson, starring as Tommy Shelby, Elizabeth "Polly" Gray, and
      Arthur Shelby, respectively, the gang's senior members. Sam Neill,
      Iddo Goldberg, Tom Hardy, Paddy Considine, Adrien Brody, Aidan
      Gillen, Annabelle Wallis, Charlotte Riley, Sam Claflin, Stephen
      Graham, and Anya Taylor-Joy also have recurring roles at various
      times of the series. The show premiered on 12 September 2013,
      telecast on BBC Two until the fourth series, and then shifted to BBC
      One for the fifth and upcoming sixth series. The fifth series
      premiered on BBC One on 25 August 2019 and finished on 22 September
      2019. Netflix, under the deal with Weinstein Company and Endemol,
      had acquired the rights to release Peaky Blinders in the United
      States and around the world. In January 2021, it was announced that
      series six would be the last.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div className='shelby'>
    <img src="https://cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/larazon/PG2U3V4VJVGZ3MNBJGDFGRKA3Q.jpg" alt="Thomas Shelby" />
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: I think you want `min-height: 75vh` on the container, instead of `height`

Comment: @sol Exactly! appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use `min-height` instead of `height`

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #628395;
  min-height: 75vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: inherit;
}
```

Comment: that's right! thank you

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header{
  padding:50px;
  background-color: #0b090a;
  text-align: center;
  height: 6rem;
  color: #fefae0;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #628395;
  min-height: 75vh;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items:inherit;
}

.nav{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #161a1d;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav div{
  color: #fefae0;
  padding:1rem;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.aside{
  background-color: #a4161a;
  flex:2 1 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  order: 1
}

.aside p{
  font-family: 'Luxurious Roman', cursive;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.section .content {
  background-color: #fefae0;
  flex: 75%;
  padding: 1rem;
  order:0;
}

.section .shelby{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex: 75%;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  height:450px;
  background-color: #776a19
}

.section p{
  font-family: 'Luxurious Roman', cursive;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.shelby img{
  height:350px;
  width:500px;
}

footer{
  background-color: #660708;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<header className="header">
  <h1>Layout Testing</h1>
</header>

<nav className="nav">
  <div>This is the Navbar tho</div>
  <div> Barra de navegacion</div>
  <div>Seccion de rutas </div>
</nav>

<div className="container">
  <aside className="aside">
    <h2>Aside</h2>
    <p>
      Overview Peaky Blinders is an epic centered on a gangster family of
      Irish-Romani origin set in Birmingham, England, starting in 1919,
      several months after the end of the First World War in November
      1918. The story centres on the Peaky Blinders gang and their
      ambitious and highly cunning boss Tommy Shelby (Cillian Murphy).
    </p>
  </aside>
  <section className="section">
    <div className="content">
    <h2>Section</h2>
    <p>
      Peaky Blinders is a British period crime drama television series
      created by Steven Knight. Set in Birmingham, England, the series
      follows the exploits of the Peaky Blinders crime gang in the direct
      aftermath of the First World War. The fictional gang is loosely
      based on a real urban youth gang of the same name, who were active
      in the city from the 1890s to the early 20th century. Peaky Blinders
      features an ensemble cast, led by Cillian Murphy, Helen McCrory, and
      Paul Anderson, starring as Tommy Shelby, Elizabeth "Polly" Gray, and
      Arthur Shelby, respectively, the gang's senior members. Sam Neill,
      Iddo Goldberg, Tom Hardy, Paddy Considine, Adrien Brody, Aidan
      Gillen, Annabelle Wallis, Charlotte Riley, Sam Claflin, Stephen
      Graham, and Anya Taylor-Joy also have recurring roles at various
      times of the series. The show premiered on 12 September 2013,
      telecast on BBC Two until the fourth series, and then shifted to BBC
      One for the fifth and upcoming sixth series. The fifth series
      premiered on BBC One on 25 August 2019 and finished on 22 September
      2019. Netflix, under the deal with Weinstein Company and Endemol,
      had acquired the rights to release Peaky Blinders in the United
      States and around the world. In January 2021, it was announced that
      series six would be the last.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div className='shelby'>
    <img src="https://cloudfront-eu-central-1.images.arcpublishing.com/larazon/PG2U3V4VJVGZ3MNBJGDFGRKA3Q.jpg" alt="Thomas Shelby" />
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```